# OTFUEL_APP_TOKEN' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js, windows, nlp, chatbot

I am trying to work with botfuel, in order to run the bot I need to input the credential of app am creating. so when am about to use the credentials the error message to pops up

```
$Env:BOTFUEL_APP_TOKEN=<app_token>; 
$Env:BOTFUEL_APP_KEY = <app_key>; 
$Env:BOTFUEL_APP_ID = <app_id>;
```

npm start config tried this already. It's not working . I work on windows 10 in cmd.

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\project\botfuel-sample-starter>BOTFUEL_APP_TOKEN= XXXXX BOTFUEL_APP_ID=xxxxx BOTFUEL_APP_KEY=xxxxx npm run start
'BOTFUEL_APP_TOKEN' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use following on powershell :

```
$Env:BOTFUEL_APP_TOKEN=<...>; $Env:BOTFUEL_APP_ID=<...>; $Env:BOTFUEL_APP_KEY=<...>; npm start
```